# PHP Array, Dynamic Array Name or Other Technique

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I have inherited a project where I need to add data to a table in the following format.

```
Fitness101,FT101,EA101,RX101
```

What I am getting in one array is the following:

```
Fitness101,FT101
Fitness101,EA101
Fitness101,RX101
Fitness102,FT102
Fitness102,EA102
Fitness102,RX102
Fitness103,FT103
Fitness103,EA103
Fitness103,RX103
```

I need to group the classes for each fitness level and add the following 3 records/rows:

```
Fitness101,FT101,EA101,RX101
Fitness102,FT102,EA102,RX102
Fitness103,FT103,EA103,RX103
```

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

I tried several if/while/foreach statements/loops but no luck.

Can a dynamic array name be used or am I am making this more complicated than necessary?

Thanks.

If I print the array it looks like this:

```
[0] => Fitness101,FT101
[1] => Fitness101,EA101
[2] => Fitness101,RX101
[4] => Fitness102,FT102
[5] => Fitness102,EA102
[6] => Fitness102,RX102
[7] => Fitness103,EA103
[8] => Fitness103,EA103
[9] => Fitness103,RX103
```

---

I solved this by looping through each title for the class code and creating a new array based on the title.

Comment: Is what you're starting with a multidimensional array, an array of strings, one long string, or what? Can you edit the question to show what you're starting with in PHP code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your input is formatted in the following way:

```
$entries = [
    "Fitness101,FT101",
    "Fitness101,EA101",
    "Fitness101,RX101",
    "Fitness102,FT102",
    "Fitness102,EA102",
    "Fitness102,RX102",
    "Fitness103,FT103",
    "Fitness103,EA103",
    "Fitness103,RX103"
];

$levels = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    list($level, $class) = explode(',', $entry);
    if (!isset($levels[$level])) {
        $levels[$level] = $level;
    }
    $levels[$level] .= ','.$class;
}
$levels = array_values($levels);

echo json_encode($levels);
// Prints:
// ["Fitness101,FT101,EA101,RX101","Fitness102,FT102,EA102,RX102","Fitness103,FT103,EA103,RX103"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual for this type of grouping problem, you can use the column you wish to group by as a key in your result array. If you are starting with an array in this format:

```
$your_array = [
    ['Fitness101','FT101'],
    ['Fitness101','EA101'],
    // etc.
];
```

Then it would work like this:

```
foreach ($your_array as $row) {
    $result[$row[0]][0] = $row[0];  // write or overwrite the first column
    $result[$row[0]][] = $row[1];   // append the subsequent columns
}
```

Here `$row[0]` is the first column with "Fitness101", etc., and when you use it as a key in the `$result` array, you'll be adding each of the values into a column in a row indicated by that key, so they'll be grouped together as in your desired output.

---

If you have an array of strings instead, then it's pretty much the same, just explode the row first.

```
$your_array = [
    'Fitness101,FT101',
    'Fitness101,EA101',
    // etc.
];

foreach ($your_array as $row) {
    $row = explode(',', $row);
    $result[$row[0]][0] = $row[0];
    $result[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}
```